# Please rate my understanding of eigenvalues and eigenvectors with differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Im am going through the book "Linear Algebra and Its Applications" by Gilbert Strang and chapter 5 has given me a hard time so I wanted to take a step back and see if I understood everything correctly...

1. We have a system of equations $\frac{du}{dt} = Au$ meaning that we have the derivative of the function that controls the system which means we know the rate of change to the system.
2. We know from number one that the derivative is equal to $Au$. If...

$$
\begin{aligned}
 u(t) &= e^{\lambda t}x \\
 u'(t) &= \lambda e^{\lambda t}x \\
\end{aligned} \\
$$

we can then compare our two derivatives to make sure they make sense. Substituting $e^{\lambda t}x$ for $u$.

$$
\begin{aligned} \\
  Ae^{\lambda t}x &= \lambda e^{\lambda t}x \\
  Ax &= \lambda x
\end{aligned}
$$

3. The coefficients in the matrix $A$ stay the same since those are the parameters of our system. The functions change with time ($e^{\lambda t}x$) which in turn changes the derivatives at every moment in time.
4. The eigenvectors and eigenvalues stay the same throughout time
5. By the definition of eigenvectors, we know that $A = S \Lambda S^{-1}$. From the definition of $e^{At}$ we can find that...

$$
\begin{aligned}
  e^{At} &= S e^{\Lambda t} S^{-1} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

which is the same as $e^{\lambda t}x$. The usefulness of this is so that we can calculate the state at any point in time (given a starting point)

Comment: I cannot follow you at all, sorry. You understood that the eigenvalues belong to the matrix (not the function(s)) and remain constant because the matrix is constant?

Comment: the matrix is not constant though because the matrix represents the derivative which changes at every point in time, right? only the eigenvalues are constant

Comment: No, the matrix is most probably constant.

Comment: but in my step 4 you can see I am squaring the matrix $A$ so it is not staying the same at every time step

Comment: Let's make it as easy as possible: assume your matrix is $n\times n$ and has $n$ distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ with corresponding eigenvectors $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. Then each of the functions $e^{\lambda_1 t}x_1,\ldots,e^{\lambda_n t}x_n$ is a solution. You can linearly combine them to get new solutions: $c_1e^{\lambda_1 t}x_1 + \ldots + c_ne^{\lambda_n t}x_n$, where the $c_k$'s are numbers. These are infinitely many solutions, obviously. Only if you specify an initial value, the $c_k$'s are uniquely determined and you get a unique solution.

Comment: but I still don't get why you say the matrix A doesn't change, because the derivative which is matrix A is changing at every time step, is it not?

Comment: You don't understand anything, sorry to say this. Your equation is $u'(t) = Au(t)$. So, you ask for a differentiable vector function $u$ which satisfies this equation. There are no time steps. $t$ runs continuously over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I revised the post as I realize it was all over the place. I realize now that the eigenvectors do stay constant and the derivative only changes because of the changes in time. I'd like to know your thoughts on the revision if you have a chance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is on point. Note however, that the equation $\frac{du}{dt}=Au$ has infinitely many solutions, so we say that a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ is a solution if $f'(t)=Af(t)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$.
2. Here you are essentially saying that, if $x$ is an eigenvector for A with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $e^{\lambda t}x$ is a solution. But not all matrices have eigen vectors/values, hence this approach is only useful in this special case.
3. Yes, but the solution is not nessecarily on the form $u(t)=e^{\lambda t}x$, but yes $u(t)$ is dependent on the time variable $t$.
4. Yes.
5. This does not follow from the definition of eigen vectors, but from the notion of being diagonalizable. So in order to write $A=S\Lambda S^{-1}$ we must first assume that $A$ is diagonizable, which it is if there exists a basis of eigen vectors for $A$. The identity $e^{At}=Se^{\Lambda t} S^{-1}$ is very useful for computing $e^{At}$, however it is not the same as $e^{\lambda t}x$. $e^{At}$ is matrix and $e^{\lambda t}x$ is a vector.

Knowing $e^{At}$ is very useful, because $(e^{At})'=Ae^{At}=e^{At}A$, hence for any vector x we have that $(e^{At}x)' = A(e^{At}x)$, hence $u(t)=e^{At}x$ is a solution.